# Почему не работает первый код? а второй работает отлично

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, form

```html
<div class="lole">

  Обратная сзязь ,Оставте ваш номер телефона и мы вам перезвоним<br>




  <form method="post" name="form" id="2">
    <br><input type="text" id="form_name" pattern="^[А-Яа-яЁё\s]+${1,17}" placeholder="Ваше имя" name="name">
    <br><input type="tel" id="form_tel" pattern="[0-9+]{9,11}" placeholder="Ваш номер телефона" name="numb">
    <br><textarea type="text" id="form_zak" placeholder="Ваш заказ" name="text"></textarea>
  </form> <input id="go" onclick="senddata();" type="submit" name="go" value="Отправить" />

  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function senddata() {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "cod.php",
        data: {
          mes: $('#form_name').val(),
          num: $('#form_tel').val(),
          mees: $('#form_zak').val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
          $('#res').html(data)
        }
      })
    }
  </script>
  <div id="res"></div>
</div>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<div class="calcule">
  <h1>Расчёт стоимости</h1>
  Место
  <form method="post">
    <select name="mes" id="mes">

            <option  value="700">Архангельское село,Хохольский район</option>
            <option  value="1100">Анна</option>
            <option  value="370">Александровка</option>
            <option  value="400">Бабяково</option>
            <option  value="1100">Бобров</option>
            <option  value="400">Берёзовка</option>
            <option  value="700">Архангельское село,Хохольский район</option>
            <option  value="700">Архангельское село,Хохольский район</option>
            <option  value="700">Архангельское село,Хохольский район</option>
            <option  value="700">Архангельское село,Хохольский район</option>
            <option  value="700">Архангельское село,Хохольский район</option>
            <option  value="700">Архангельское село,Хохольский район</option>
            <option  value="700">Архангельское село,Хохольский район</option>
            <option  value="700">Архангельское село,Хохольский район</option>
            <option  value="700">Архангельское село,Хохольский район</option>

        </select> М
    <sup><small>3</small></sup><input name="num" id="nem" type="number" min="1" step="1">
    <br> Марка<select name="mees" id="mees">

            <option  value="3150">m100</option>
            <option  value="3250">m150</option>
            <option  value="3400">m200</option>


        </select>


  </form>
  <input id="go" onclick="senddata();" type="submit" name="go" value="=" />


  <div id="resp"></div>
</div>




<div class="contact">
  <h1>Контактные данные:</h1>

  <q>89023425523 </q> <q>5zcvxz@mail.ru</q> <q>5xhsxry@gmail.com</q>
  <p>
    <a name="topes"></a>
  </p>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  function senddata() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "cod2.php",
      data: {
        mes: $('#mes').val(),
        num: $('#nem').val(),
        mees: $('#mees').val()
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $('#resp').html(data)
      }
    })
  }
</script>
```

php код точно правильный потомучто подключал через include и всё работало а теперь не хочет через ajax в чём ошибка первого кода?

Comment: не работает всёравно(

Answer (score 0):

У вас input type = “submit” находится не в форме